# SQL Server  'select * into' versus 'insert into ..select *

Tags: sql-server, select-into

Say `table1` and `table2` already exist, is there any difference between these queries

query1 :-

```
select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1
```

query2: -

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO vs SELECT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947983/insert-into-vs-select-into) and several others

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1` creates table1 and inserts the values of table2 in them. So, if the table is already created that statement would give an error.

The `insert into table1 select * from table2` only inserts the values of table2 in table1.

Comment: I was not aware of the error that would be generated by query-1 if the table existed . Thank you very much !

Answer (score 8):

The first one ([`SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)) will create and populate a new table the second ([`INSERT... SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)) inserts to an existing table.

In versions of SQL Server prior to 2008 the first one could be minimally logged and the second one not but [this is no longer true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

In below query, `table1` will be created or an error will be thrown if it already exists

```
select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1
```

In below query, the table `table1` *must* exist before running the command

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1
```

The query above requires that the table DOES NOT exist. You do not need to specify columns as all columns are created as they are retrieved from the source table.

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

For the above query, you need an EXISTING table1.
The columns in both tables should also be in exactly the same order, otherwise you need to provide a column list for both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

Is a commonly used sentence, which is used to insert values of a table into another table. Selected columns can also be inserted using this.

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE_A FROM TABLE_B
```

Will create a new TABLE_A populated with values of TABLE_B

Answer (score 0):

a) select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1
-If table1 and table2 already exist, you will get below error when you execute the query.
"Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'table1' in the database"

b) insert into table1 select * from table2
-If table1 is duplicate of table2 ,then this query consider common insert statement
Exp: select * into table1 from table2 where 1=0
However bare in mind, you will accumulate duplicate data each time you execute the query.