# Temp table already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a temporary table in which I am trying to insert records based on a where condition but it throws an error that it already exists. 
I have tried to change the names but that is not the issue as the temporary tables are delete when the session ends.

I think I am writing the query right.

```
   SELECT [Name]
        INTO #TEMP_REJECT
        FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION
        WHERE Name = @Name
```

I am trying to insert #TEMP_REJECT FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION

**Error message**

> "There is already an object named '#TEMP_REJECT' in the database."

Please suggest.

Thank you for your help.
R

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message you encounter ? Also give us the table definitions.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question with error message 'There is already an object named '#TEMP_REJECT' in the database.'

Comment: Off topic, it might be worth considering table variables instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server won't tell you that a table doesn't exist if it doesn't.

I suggest that you add

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_REJECT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_REJECT
```

in front of your select statement. This guarantees that the temp table won't exist when the select is executed.

So your statement becomes

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_REJECT') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #TEMP_REJECT

 SELECT [Name]
            INTO #TEMP_REJECT
            FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION
            WHERE Name = @Name
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560644/3635715

To make short : `SELECT INTO` creates table then insert records.
`INSERT INTO` only insert the records.

So in your case, since `#TEMP_REJECT` already exists, `SELECT INTO` is rejected because it cannot create the table again, so you have to use `INSERT INTO` after first `SELECT INTO`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_REJECT') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #TEMP_REJECT
  SELECT [Name]
  FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION
  WHERE Name = @Name
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT [Name]
  INTO #TEMP_REJECT
  FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION
  WHERE Name = @Name
END
```

References :
[INTO Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)
[INSERT Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)

Comment: Isn't there a way of doing this without duplicating code?

Comment: Of course, you can drop the temporary table before doing SELECT INTO if the temporary table already exists

Answer (score 1):

Try checking before inserting

if object_id('tempdb..#TEMP_REJECT') is not null
drop table #TEMP_REJECT

```
SELECT [Name]
        INTO #TEMP_REJECT
        FROM #TEMP_VALIDATION
        WHERE Name = @Name
```

if SQL says,there is temp table,there must be a table prior to your insert

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that I get the same error when I am working consecutively through the same SQL Server tab/file.

For example, I have a large SQL file that I use to execute a series of updates using temp tables. When I execute it consecutively, it errors out complaining that my #tempTable already exists (even if I use a "if this table exists, drop it" statement as DeanOC describes).

Exiting out of the file/tab between consecutive runs resolves the issue.

If this poses an issue for your use case, I'd suggest bundling your statements in a stored proc and implementing DeanOC's drop logic therein.

Comment: Yes, apparently this was also my issue when running a large SQL file in SQL Server Management Studio. NOTE: It may fix the problem to surround your SQL with BEGIN/END