# Difference between INSERT INTO and SELECT INTO when calling OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select 1 as X,d.* into [TravelData] from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=<redacted>',
     'exec [OtherDB].[GetTravelData]  1, ''28-Nov-2016 16:00'', ''28-Nov-2016 19:00''') as d
```

I have this as a way to slurp remote DB into a local table. This syntax appears to work BUT I get error:

> There is already an object named 'TravelData' in the database.

Makes sense, SELECT INTO is *supposed* to create the table. But thinking I'd simply change `SELECT` to `INSERT` I then get syntax errors. What should the correct syntax be to get this data into an existing DB table whose structure matches the query output?

Comment: I think you mean "`SELECT INTO` is supposed to create the **table**", not DB. You can read a comparison of `SELECT INTO` and `INSERT INTO` here: [INSERT INTO vs SELECT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947983/insert-into-vs-select-into). The answer below from [Prdp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp) seems to deal with your specific situation perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `INSERT INTO SELECT` syntax

```
INSERT INTO [TravelData]
            (X,
             col1,
             col2,
             ...)
SELECT 1 AS X,
       d.col1,
       d.col2,
       .....
FROM   OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                  'Server=<redacted>',
                  'exec [OtherDB].[GetTravelData]  1, ''28-Nov-2016 16:00'', ''28-Nov-2016 19:00''') AS d
```

**Note :** Instead of `*` in `select` list add the `column` list. Also in `Insert` mention the column list

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with using OPENROWSET.

`INSERT INTO ...` requires that the table already exist.

`SELECT ... INTO` requires that the table *not* exist.  The table will be created by the statement using the columns defined in the SELECT.