# How to know how many rows have been inserted till now?

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2012

Question 1:

I'm running a query like this:

```
select * 
into table 
from view
```

The view has a lot of calculations and the query is running for over 15 hours. I know how many rows I need to have in the data. Is there a way to know how many rows were insert to table till now so I will know if to keep with this process or find another way to execute this.

Question 2: is the `Insert into , select from` more efficient than `select * into`? when you are trying to move data from view to a table?

Thanks

Comment: Question 2 : Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947983/insert-into-vs-select-into)

Comment: Did you try simply `select count(*) from table`?

Comment: yes. It takes a lot of time also. I'll try to find a way to make my code more efficient.

Comment: @Toto88. I cant understand your full explanation. 
However, I suggest you that try, `select @@rowcount`, after run your `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

try

select count(*) from table