# Get the results sets of a parametrized query `rbind`ed *and* directly in the database using R's `DBI`

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi

Using `package:DBI`, I need to:

1. run a parametrized query with different parameters (i.e. a vector of parameters);
2. get the results sets concatenated (i.e. `rbind`ed as per R terminology or `union`ed as per SQL terminology);
3. and get the resulting table in the database for further manipulation.

[`dbBind()`](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbbind)/`dbGetquery()` fullfils requirements 1 and 2, but I then need to write the resulting data frame to the database using `dbWriteTable()`, which is ineficient:

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

res <- dbGetQuery(con,
                  "select * from iris where Species = ?",
                  params = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")))

dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", res)
```

Conversely, `dbExecute()` fulfils requirement 3, but I don't think it has the "`rbind` feature". Of course, this throw an error because the table would get overwritten:

```r
dbExecute(con,
          "create table mytable as select * from iris where Species = ?",
          params = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")))
```

What is the most efficient/recommended way of doing so?

Notes:

- I am not the DBA and can only access the database through R.
- My example is too trivial and could be achieved in a single query. My use case really requires a parametrized query to be run multiple times with different parameters.
- I have to use Oracle, but I am interested in a solution even if it don't works with Oracle.

Comment: Instead of query/download/combine/upload, why not use a parameterized query that inserts directly into a (temp?) table such as using `SELECT INTO ...`.

Comment: I didn't have the idea! Could you please provide more details in an answer? (I'm quite new to SQL.) Thank you very much!

Comment: Searching `oracle select into` returns several good links, I won't regurgitate them here. You can probably do something like your `create table mytable as ...` above with your _first_ query, and then from there do `select  * into mytable from iris where Species=?` for each of your individual queries (no need to try to "union" them, frankly, though you can, perhaps with CTEs or such.

Comment: FYI, you say *"parameterized query to be run multiple times"*, it might be possible to convert that process into something more fluid. If your parameters are (say) a `obj <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=3:4, d=7:8)` and you want to submit queries based on each _row_ of this frame, then perhaps: (1) insert this into a temporary table; (2) `select ... from realtable rt inner join mytemp mt on rt.a=mt.a and rt.e between mt.b and mt.d`; (3) clean up (remove the temp table). This can be done either as a "download" or as a "select into" methodology.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It showed me a method that I didn't know and allowed me to solve my issue. I found I have to use [`INSERT INTO` instead of `SELECT INTO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947983/11148823) if the table that collects the results already exists. I posted an answer with the method I used. Comments are welcome!

Comment: And many thanks for your second comment showing a more fluid approach. This cannot apply to my concrete use case (my example is too simple), but I will used it for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @r2evans comment and @G.Grothendieck answer, instead of query/download/combine/upload, I used a parameterized query that inserts directly into a table.

First, I created the table with the appropriate columns to collect the results:

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

create_table <-
"
CREATE TABLE
  warpbreaks2 (
    breaks real,
    wool text,
    tension text
);
"

dbExecute(con, create_table)
```

Then I executed an `INSERT INTO` step:

```r
dbWriteTable(con, "warpbreaks", warpbreaks)

insert_into <-
"
INSERT INTO
  warpbreaks2
SELECT
  warpbreaks.breaks,
  warpbreaks.wool,
  warpbreaks.tension
FROM
  warpbreaks
WHERE
  tension = ?;
"

dbExecute(con, insert_into, params = list(c("L", "M")))
```

---

This is a dummy example for illustration purpose. It could be achieve more directly with e.g.:

```r
direct_query <-
"
CREATE TABLE
  warpbreaks3 AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  warpbreaks
WHERE
  tension IN ('L', 'M');
"

dbExecute(con, direct_query )
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Create the table with the first parameter and then insert each of the others into it.

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

parms <- c("setosa", "versicolor")

dbExecute(con, "create table mytable as
  select * from iris where Species = ?",
  params = parms[1])
for (p in parms[-1]) {
  dbExecute(con, "insert into mytable
    select * from iris where Species = ?",
    params = p)
}

# check
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from mytable")
str(res)
```

**2)**  Alternately generate the text of an SQL statement to do it all.  sqldf pulls in RSQLite and gsubfn which supplies fn$ that enables the text substitution.

```
library(sqldf)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

parms <- c("setosa", "versicolor")
parmString <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", parms))
fn$dbExecute(con, "create table mytable as
  select * from iris where Species in ($parmString)")

# check
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from mytable")
str(res)
```

**3)** A variation of (2) is to insert the appropriate number of question marks.

```
library(sqldf)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

params <- list("setosa", "versicolor")
quesString <- toString(rep("?", length(params)))

fn$dbExecute(con, "create table mytable as
  select * from iris where Species in ($quesString)", params = params)

# check
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from mytable")
str(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer helped me to build a similar approach. I posted an answer with the method I used. Comments are welcome!